# Create simple xpath expression with 'or' operator and a function

Tags: xml, selenium, xpath, appium

Can I make the following xpath expression to be simpler:

```
//*[translate(text(), 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ' ,'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')='word1' or translate(text(), 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ' ,'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')='word2']
```

The above fine work, but so long, maybe there is an excellent way.

I'm thinking whether I can put this function just once:

```
text() 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ' 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
```

It's possible? or is there other approach?

Comment: I have never tried translate function though, but can you try with contains() probably.

Comment: You don't tag this with an XPath version but I guess it must be XPath 1.0 because with later versions of XPath, the solution would be trivial.

Comment: No, I can't think of a simpler way of doing this in XPath 1.0. Give the vendors of Selenium a kick up the backside and tell them you need support for XPath 2.0 or preferably 3.1. Remind them that XPath 1.0 is 20 years old in a few weeks's time -- why are they still using something so ancient and long superseded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I make the following xpath expression to be simpler:
>
> ```
> //*[translate(text(), 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ' ,'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')='word1' 
>    or translate(text(), 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ' ,'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')='word2']
> ```

**Use**:

```
//*[text()[starts-with(translate(., 'WORD', 'word'), 'word') 
          and substring(.,5) = 1 or substring(.,5) = 2]]
```

===============================

**XSLT - based verification**:

This transformation:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="//*[text()[starts-with(translate(., 'WORD', 'word'), 'word')
          and substring(.,5) = 1 or substring(.,5) = 2]]">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on this source XML document:**

```
<t>
  <a>
    <b>Word2</b>
    <c>word3</c>
    <d>word1</d>
    <e>Word11</e>
    <f>Xxx</f>
  </a>
</t>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result** -- copied to the output only elements that match the XPath expression:

```
<b>Word2</b>
<d>word1</d>
```

---

**Update**:  In a comment the OP clarified that he wants an XPath 1.0 expression that checks if a given string is one of two other given strings or not.

**Here is one way to do this in XPath 1.0**:

```
contains(concat('|', $s1, '|', $s2, '|'), concat('|', $s, '|'))
```

We check that the left+right concatenation of the given string `$s` is a substring (is contained) in the concatenation of the two other given strings `$s1` and `$s2` so that the same character -- `|` is the left-most, the right-most and the delimiter between the two strings.

Here we use '|' as the delimiter, but any string that is known not to be contained in `$s` can be used -- such as ?, $$$, etc.

**Then the already provided solution above can be rewritten in this way:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match=
  "//*[text()[contains('|word1|word2|',
                        concat('|',translate(., 'WORD', 'word'), '|')
                       )]
       ]">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the same XML document (above), the same correct result is produced**:

```
<b>Word2</b>
<d>word1</d>
```

Comment: Sorry, It hasn't answered the question. The point is can I create following pattern: `text() 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ' 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz' 'word1' or 'word2'`. Not repeat the translate function, but I can use for search some `words`. It's possible?

Comment: @frianH **Exactly** this is done in the solution -- `translate()` is used only once. And the long ABCD--Z abcd--z strings are gone

Comment: @frianH, I think I now understand what you are asking. Please see the update at the end of my answer -- it provides the wanted solution. Can you, please, confirm this?

Comment: Awesome, it worked. By the way why you mentioned **XPath 1.0**? Is later version different and so simpler?

Comment: @frianH in XPath 2.0 or greater versions one can simply have this expression: `$s = ($s1, $s2)`

Answer (score 0):

If you are checking visibility of both values, But you try iosNSPredicate here try something like this "type == \"XCUIElementTypeStaticText\" AND (name == \"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ\" OR name == \"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz\")";